# How do I add a line break for read command?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
 read -p "Please Enter a Message:" message
```

How can I add a line break after `Message:`?

Comment: You might consider updating the accepted answer to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15696250/1048539) as it's far less hacky (and less confusing to us future visitors...).

Comment: If you want to include shell variables in the prompt, then I think you’re going to need to use the, e.g., `read -p "$name, Please Enter a Message:"$'\n' message` form — described in the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39581815/441757 — because you can’t use shell variables in the all-single-quoted `read -p $'Please Enter a Message:\n' message` form.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I like [Huang F. Lei's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296108/how-do-i-add-a-line-break-for-read-command/4296147#4296147), but if you don't like the literal line break, this works:

```
read -p "Please Enter a Message: `echo $'\n> '`" message
```

Shows:

```
Please Enter a Message:
> _
```

...where `_` is where the cursor ends up. Note that since trailing newlines are usually dropped during command substitution, I've included the `>` afterward. But actually, your original question doesn't seem to want that prompt bit, so:

```
# Get a carriage return into `cr` -- there *has* to be a better way to do this
cr=`echo $'\n.'`
cr=${cr%.}

# Use it
read -p "Please Enter a Message: $cr" message
```

Shows

```
Please Enter a Message:
_
```

There has to be a better way, though.

Comment: I hope there's a better way :)

Comment: @Doug: Yeah. Just updated with a *slight* improvement. I'm still not happy with it. :-)

Comment: @Doug: Although now I think about it, since `echo` (like `read`) is a bash built-in, although the above is a tad awkward at least it's not unnecessarily spawning processes.

Comment: You can directly assign the linefeed like so: (works in bash v3) `cr=$'\n'`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39581815/2572431) is the better way you're looking for.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Even though `echo` is a builtin, command substitution spawns a new process to run the command in.

Comment: Another better way: `echo "Please enter message: $cr"; read -p "" message`

Answer (score 105):

Just looking for the exact same thing. You can use:

```
# -r and -e options are unrelated to the answer.
read -rep $'Please Enter a Message:\n' message
```

And it will work exactly as asked:

```
Please enter a Message:
_
```

Here is an extract from the [bash manpage on *ANSI-C Quoting*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) explaining it:

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word expands to
> string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by  the
> ANSI  C  standard.  Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded
> as follows:
>
> - (...)
> - \n     new line
> - (...)
>
> The expanded result is single-quoted, as if the  dollar  sign  had  not
> been present.

Took me a while to find out.

Note that single quotes and double quotes behave differently in this regard, as pointed out under [*Locale-Specific Translation*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Locale-Translation.html):

> A  double-quoted  string  preceded  by a dollar sign ($) will cause the
> string to be translated according to the current locale.  If  the  cur-
> rent  locale  is C or POSIX, the dollar sign is ignored.  If the string
> is translated and replaced, the replacement is double-quoted.

Comment: @t-j-crowder This is a better way, the one [T.J. Crowder](http://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) was hinting to :)

Comment: what does `-e` exactly do? it works with me without that `-e`, `-e` causes only for me that `-s` doesn't work any more.

Comment: For those wondering, $'something' aka dollar-string seems to be POSIX-compliant (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism for short-info, http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=249 for more detail).

Answer (score 47):

Here's an improvement on the accepted answer that doesn't require spawning a subshell:

```
read -p "Please Enter a Message:"$'\n' message
```

From the [GNU Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting):

> Words of the form `$'string'` are treated specially. The word expands to *string*, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.

Comment: The most concise answer here. +1

Comment: Added benefit: allows interpolation: `read -p "My prompt (default: $interpolated_var)"$'\n' message`

Answer (score 18):

```
$ read -p "Please Enter a Message:
> " message
Please Enter a Message:
```

Typing a "newline" between ':' and '"' directly.

Comment: neat solution, but might confuse someone reading the code later.

Comment: It's what works for me, because I also have a variable, and with the `read -p "$(echo -e 'Please Enter a Message: \n\b')" message` solution, it prints the variable name literally. This solution expands properly.

Answer (score 12):

Just to improve the answers of [Huang F. Lei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296108/how-do-i-add-a-line-break-for-read-command/4296147#4296147) and of [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296108/how-do-i-add-a-line-break-for-read-command/4296147#4296177) which I like (and added +1) ..
You can use one of the following syntaxes too, which basically are the same, it depends on your taste (I prefer the first one):

```
read -p "$(echo -e 'Please Enter a Message: \n\b')" message
read -p "`echo -e 'Please Enter a Message: \n\b'`" message
```

which both will produce the following output:

```
Please Enter a Message: 
_
```

where _ is the cursor.
In case you need a newline in any part of the string but the end, you can use `\n`, for example

```
read -p "`echo -e '\nPlease Enter\na Message: '`" message
```

will produce

```
.
Please Enter
a Message: _
```

where . is a blank first new line and _ is the cursor.

Only to add a final trailing newline you have to use `\n\b` as in my first example

Answer (score 4):

From the `bash` manpage:

```
-p prompt
   Display prompt on standard error, without a trailing new-
   line, before attempting to read any input.  The prompt is
   displayed only if input is coming from a terminal.
```

So, not with `read` itself, and putting `\n` in the message string just echoes `\n`.  The answer should be simple though - don't get `read` to display the prompt:

```
echo "Please Enter a Message:" 1>&2
read message
```

Comment: But the `echo` will happen whether input is coming from a terminal or not; the message `read` displays won't.

Comment: fair point, _if_ the script is going to be used non-interactively.

Answer (score 0):

```
read -p "$(printf 'Please Enter a Message:\n')" message
```

With `printf`you can use `\n` for line breaks.

Answer (score -3):

`read -p "Please Enter a Message:`<kbd>Return</kbd>`" message`

Comment: Doesn't work for me with bash on Ubuntu 10.04. You sure about your syntax there?

Comment: Maybe you mean to hit the return key as the Huang F. Lei solution?