# How can I get bash read -p to print a new line

Tags: bash

I am using Bash build-in `read -p` to print message and read user input into REPLY, want a new line at end.

read -p "please input someint\n" did not work, it printed `\n` rather than a new line.

How do I do that ?

thanks

Comment: a vote down, interesting

Comment: Probably because it's a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296108/how-do-i-add-a-line-break-for-read-command

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please input something
" msg
echo $msg
```

This will make `read -p` print a new line. Hope this helps.